# Encrypting HTTP POST data

Tags: http, post, https

I have a HTTP POST string that I am running from a client cpp program against a server running Apache. Following is the POST string that would get fired from the clients:

```
"POST %s HTTP/1.0\r\n" 
"Host: %s\r\n"
"Content-type: multipart/form-data\r\n"
"Content-length: %d\r\n\r\n"
"Content-Disposition: %s; filename: %s\n"
```

It would be nice if someone could help me out to understand how could I encrypt the data that sits in the `Content-Disposition:` field.
Also, I noticed that even if I put something irrelevant to the right of the POST string, like: `"POST %s HTTPGarbage/1.0\r\n"`, the transfer still happens, it would be grand if I am informed about this behavior as well.

Comment: Are you using HTTP or HTTPS? Your question is tagged both.

Comment: Well I was guessing if there is a way to use HTTPS in encryption of the data, and hence the tag.

Comment: Indeed, if you use HTTPS, all the data is automatically encrypted.

Comment: Yeah, there's a confusion I have regarding that. If I just specify my host/server to be something like "https://someplace/..." is it guaranteed that all data transfers to that host would be encrypted?

Comment: Note that your code will break if the filename contains a character not allowed in tokens, such as a space character.

Comment: I guess I'll answer what's on my head. A browser would normally handle the SSL encryption, but since there is no browser at the client side, so I would probably need to use a SSL library or something to encrypt the data myself. Yes Julian, I would be checking the filename for conformance before sending the payload.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use HTTPS (which is essentially HTTP over SSL/TLS), all the HTTP traffic will be encrypted from the moment the SSL/TLS connection is established (provided you're using the appropriate cipher suites), that it, before any HTTP communication. Only the server certificate (which may reveal the host name) will be visible, and perhaps the client certificate in some circumstances (if you're also using client-certificate authentication). The URL and all the HTTP headers (and content) will be protected with SSL/TLS this way.

If you're not using a browser as a client you can make use of existing SSL/TLS libraries such as NSS (Mozilla) or OpenSSL. Make sure you configure the certificate trust and host name verification correctly.

Comment: I forgot to say you might be interested in something like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/https.html).

Comment: Actually I am not too keen on using libraries, mainly because they would increase the size (OpenSSL is around 3.5M) of the software...we just need to transfer one single fat file per client to a server (the data is also not supersensitive), no credential handshaking involved. I am thinking of writing a simple-custom encryption that would work most of the times.